# Is there any good iPhone stand with high-quality microphone for my desk?

Tags: microphone, iphone

I use my iPhone 4 to go jogging and at some point the built-in mic has gotten damaged and the only way to talk to people is via an earbud with mic.

I am looking for a desk charger which also has a high-quality mic so that I can take calls from my desk, hands-free. Does anyone know of a suitable product?

Comment: Which iPhone model is it?

Comment: Updated: It's a 4 but I guess it applies to 4S also...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no product that provides a stand and charger with a mic, but there are several external mics you can clip onto the iPhone. Some (lower quality) use the headphone jack, and some (higher quality) use the 30-pin docking port.

Here are two examples:

[IK Multimedia iRig Mic Cast](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/news/?item_id=1147)

This mic uses the headphone jack.

[image]

[Tascam iM2W stereo mic](http://tascam.com/product/im2w/)

This mic uses the docking port, but has a pass-through USB connection that permits charging while the mic is in use.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [Apple's own dock](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC596ZM/B?fnode=MTY1NDAzOQ). There's an audio plug which will allow you to plug in any microphone you like, either directly (if it's iPhone compatible) or with a [breakout cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002SK66OY).

Then you can connect any non-USB microphone you like.